# How to change column width in RecyclerView? (Android)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, width

I have a RecyclerView and a LinearLayoutManager. Each line consists of a CheckBox and two TextViews.

How can I set the width of each TextView to the maximum width of its "column" so that the columns are left-aligned?

In the screenshot, I want the b's in the second "column" left-aligned.

[image: screenshot]

I've tried the following:

```
   public void test(View view)
   {
      int max = 10;

      for (int i = 0; i < recyclerView.getLayoutManager().getChildCount(); i++)
      {
         View v = recyclerView.getLayoutManager().findViewByPosition(i);

         TextView tv1 = v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

         if (tv1.getWidth() > max)
            max = tv1.getWidth();
      }

      for (int i = 0; i < recyclerView.getLayoutManager().getChildCount(); i++)
      {
         View v = recyclerView.getLayoutManager().findViewByPosition(i);

         TextView tv1 = v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

         tv1.setWidth(max);
      }
```

This does not work and has the effect that the width of "axxx" get's smaller so that the letters are painted one below the other. The first loop correctly calculates the maximum width but after asigning the width in the second loop the text somehow collapses (because of WRAP_CONTENT?).

Edit: xml-file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="CheckBox" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="TextView" />
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I want to have the items look like in a table.

Comment: Can you please provide your XML of the row you want to edit like this? If I understand you correctly you want your b's to be lined under each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `textView.getWidth()` it will usually return 0 value, that is why your max never changes. To get the real width of the `TextView` you need to use `getMeasuredWidth()` like this:

```
textView1.measure(0,0);
if (textView1.getMeasuredWidth() > max) {
   max = textView1.getMeasuredWidth();
}

textView2.setWidth(max);
```

And with that you get this:

[image]

But be careful. If your first `TextView` width is too large it could push your second `TextView` out of the layout. You need to check the device width and/or set `maxWidth` to the desired value. I don't know how sure you can be that your data won't ever create this issue in the future. Happy coding!

Comment: Looking for where I can run this code. When the adapter is created and loaded with data the widths can't be calculated because they haven't been drawn. I can run a separate routine, for example on a button, but not before it is initially displayed. Any thoughts?